# Wip process interface api takes too much time in R12.2.5 instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracle-ebs, oracleapplications

I have a performance issue in one private API of Proces interface of Work In Process "**wip_movProc_priv.processIntf**". It takes around 2.5 Minutes for all transaction and

When I run this API in R12.1.3 instance it not take this much amount of time.

```
wip_movProc_priv.processIntf (p_group_id       => p_group_id,
                                    p_proc_phase     => WIP_CONSTANTS.MOVE_VAL,
                                    p_time_out       => 0,
                                    p_move_mode      => 3, --WIP_CONSTANTS.ONLINE,
                                    p_bf_mode        => WIP_CONSTANTS.ONLINE,
                                    p_mtl_mode       => WIP_CONSTANTS.ONLINE,
                                    p_endDebug       => 'T',
                                    p_initMsgList    => 'T',
                                    p_insertAssy     => 'T',
                                    p_do_backflush   => 'F',
                                    x_returnStatus   => x_returnstatus);
```

Please help me.

Thanks,
Yasin Musani

Answer (score 0):

This question has actually far too little detail to be answered.
Typically, the majority of time spent for Oracle EBS code execution is due to few badly performing SQLs.
You can identify the offending SQLs by looking at the AWR or SGA e.g. using Blitz Reports [DBA AWR SQL Performance Summary](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/dba-awr-sql-performance-summary/) or [DBA SGA SQL Performance Summary](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/dba-sga-sql-performance-summary/) and would then need to analyze further why these are not executing properly.